# load another view controller into UItabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

After logging UIViewController,  I am redirected to first item of UITabBarController. This works fine, but in my first viewcontrollers I want to push another view controller into the tabor view.This should happen while I logged in first time.  In other words I want to replace the selected viewcontroller with another one.  This UIViewController is not attached with Tabbar controller, I do not want to attach because it replace the first tabView item only one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding new tabs to a tab bar controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23332718/adding-new-tabs-to-a-tab-bar-controller)

Comment: No, that post for adding new tab items. But I need to show a UIViewcontroller (which is outside the tabbarcontroller), but need to replace it with a tabview.

Answer (score 0):

You will run into problems if you try to transition to another view controller in viewDidLoad. You should either switch the child view controllers of the tab bar controller or you can present a subview within one of the child view controllers.

When -viewDidLoad is called, the view controller is generally not presented. As such, if you try to present another controller, it will crash.

Try -viewDidAppear: if you want what you are describing.